# Google Contacts API doesn't show up in the list of API's available

Tags: android, google-api, google-contacts-api

I tried out the Tasks example described here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android by enabling the Tasks API in the API console but I didn't see an option for the Contacts API. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What Tasks example are you referring to?  Please provide more detail.

Comment: Here is the link for the Tasks example: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android

Comment: Ok, this is great, but check out [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to increase your chances of getting great answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Contacts API, unlike the Tasks API, doesn't need to be enabled on the APIs Console.

Please also note that the Contacts API is based on the [Google Data](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) protocol and not [Discovery](http://code.google.com/apis/discovery/).